# How do I omit blank cells in concatenate formula to make a row of individual cells appear like an address book entry?

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

How do I combine row of Excel cells (A-L) into one cell (M) to appear like an address label and omit blank cells?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by address label in this case, since I can't see your data. Answering only the concatenation and omitting blanks part with this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:L1)
```

The `TRUE` parameter means omit blanks.

##### Update after comment

Combine my first answer with your first comment, like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A2:D2),CHAR(10),E2,CHAR(10),F2,CHAR(10),TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,G2:H2),CHAR(10)TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,I2:J2),CHAR(10),TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,K2:L2))
```

Same answer, differently formatted for clarity:

```
=CONCATENATE(
    TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A2:D2),
    CHAR(10),
    E2,
    CHAR(10),
    F2,
    CHAR(10),
    TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,G2:H2),
    CHAR(10),
    TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,I2:J2),
    CHAR(10),
    TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,K2:L2)
)
```

Comment: =CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2," ",C2,"  ",D2,CHAR(10),E2,CHAR(10),F2,CHAR(10),G2,"  ",H2,CHAR(10),I2," ",J2,CHAR(10),K2," ",L2) was used to combine cell A2-AL which resulted in what I wanted except it recognized the blank cells A2-D2  result is

Comment: the wanted result would look like an address on an envelope  a1 is title, b1 is first, c1 is last, d1 is degree, e1 is facility, f1 is address, g1 is city h1 is zip, i1 is wordphone ji is phone k1 is wordfax l1 is fax m1 is where results are wanted  example a1 title (none) b1 is minnie c1 is mouse d1 is disney med center f1 is 125 fun st g1 ic anytown ok h1 is 74567 g1 phone i1 is 123-123-1234  k1 is fax l1 is 123-123-1256 result should be how an address might appear on an envelope (except for the phone and fax number)

Comment: example  line 1:  blank/skipped   line 2 125 fun st   line 3 anytown, ok 74567   line 4 is phone:  123-123-1234  line 5 is fax:  123.123.1256

Comment: I am new to this site and not exactly sure how to enter information.  I'd love to screen shot my spreadsheet, but I don't know how

Comment: @msseals, I have updated my answer after your comments. Also,  take the time to learn how to format text here. It's well worth the effort.